# How to get standard error from the odds ratio confidence interval?

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-error, odds-ratio

Given the point estimate, lower, and upper confidence limits, I'm trying to get the standard error of an odds ratio ($\hat{OR}$). Suppose that we have $1.19 [1.14, 1.23]$. Assuming it's 95% confidence interval, is that correct if I calculate $SE(\hat{OR})$ as:
$$SE(\hat{OR}) = \frac{1.23-1.19}{1.96}=0.02040816?$$

If not, how can one obtain $\hat{OR}$? Thanks!